# Pass a collection to MVC controller via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with Jquery.  I'm trying to pass my form elements back to the controller using something like this (Please note I removed success and error code for simplicity):

```
var formElements = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ScriptResolveUrl("~/Report/SubmitChanges"),
            data: {collection: formElements},
            success: 
            error:
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

My question is what should the parameter in my controller method look like:
Here is my controller method:

```
public ActionResult SubmitChanges(WHAT GOES HERE?)
{
}
```

So what I'm really looking for is what should be the type of the parameter going into the controller method?  I want to be able to retrieve the values of the form elements in the controller.

Comment: Your answer works nicely, if I was trying to pass a collection to the server I would use json.

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I did.  I have about 20-30 elements on my form so I really didn't want to have to turn each one into a parameter or list them all out in the collection.

In the jquery, I did the following:

```
 var formElements = $("#myForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ScriptResolveUrl("~/Report/SubmitChanges"),
            data: { parms: formElements },
            success:
            error: 
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

It then goes into my controller as a string:

```
public ActionResult SubmitChanges(string parms)
```

I then found a function to parse that string (seems to be working)

```
NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(parms);
```

This seems to work without listing out all of the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form elements all correspond to your model (let's say it's `MyModel`), then it should simply be:

```
public ActionResult SubmitChanges(MyModel model)
{
}
```

MVC default model binding will do the rest :).

Make sure you change your `data` definition in the jQuery ajax method though, you've already serialized it. Just do:

```
data: formElements,
```

I'm assuming the following in your jQuery ajax method is a copy and paste error?

```
success: 
error:
```

If it's not, then make sure you either remove it, or change them to:

```
success: function (result) {
    //do something
},
error: function () {
    //do something on error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I purposely omitted the code with success and error to make it more readable.  The problem is that their is no model that corresponds to my form elements.

Comment: In addition to this answer, you don't need to do: `data: {collection: formElements},`. The `serialize()` did not trick already so you just need to `data: formElements`.

Comment: @user1031516 Then you'd have to either make that action result take every single item on the form (not recommended) or just rework your page to use a model and all it's fields

Comment: @vonv. Great shout, added that too. Otherwise he'd of had to make sure the action result parameter was called `collection` :)

Comment: Right @mattytommo, I have to create my own answer based on OP's new comment.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that their is no model that corresponds to my form
>   elements.

Then you can have this:

```
public ActionResult SubmitChanges(int id, string name)
{
}
```

And then pass in the individual items:

```
var o = {
    id = $("#id_elem_id").val(),
    name = $("#name_elem_id").val()
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ScriptResolveUrl("~/Report/SubmitChanges"),
    data: JSON.stringify(o),
    success: 
    error:
    dataType: "json"
});
```

where `id_elem_id` and `name_elem_id` are the ids of your html elements. And add any additional parameters you need, just follow along.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Just get rid of the brackets around your `data` parameter:

```
var formElements = $('#myForm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ScriptResolveUrl("~/Report/SubmitChanges"),
    data: formElements,
    success: function(result) {
        // handle the success of the AJAX request
    },
    error: function() {
        // an error occurred
    }
});
```